# How to get latitude and longitude on selected grid in QGIS programatically

Tags: python, qgis

I want to an select area on a map by making a rectangle using mouse in QGIS. I want the latitude and longitude of a selected area programmatically, but I don't know  how to draw it and extract the value of it.

I want to make a grid on it and want to select one or multiple grids and extract data of selected grid with lat and long.

Comment: Have you tried anything, or do you not even know where to start?

Comment: You can start by studying this example here:

http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/108044/how-i-can-get-coordinates-by-clicking-on-the-qgis-canvas-with-pyqgis

Comment: I don't know where to start